# Django template loops unwantedly fetching items in random order

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using Django 2.2 and psql 10.8 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

I have a collection of items that I want to iterate over and render the results in a template.

They are expected to be rendered in exactly the order that they have been created in the database (by pk). However, they seem to be rendered in a random order instead.

The problem does not occur when using sqlite.

I have not found the solution for this problem; reverse iterating through the objects results also not in the desired behaviour. A simple portion of the code would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="tabs">
        {% for category in categories %}
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#{{category}}">{{category}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Say I have created four categories A, B, C, D;
when using sqlite in dev, they would be rendered in that order on the frontend page.

With psql, I am seeing an unordered result.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to show how you define `categories` in the view, and perhaps the model too.

Comment: can you show the corresponding view?

Comment: Assuming `categories` is a queryset, maybe add `.order_by(...)` to eliminate the assumption that all databases behave the same when not told what to do?

Comment: Yeah this was the 100.000. question tagged with "postgresql" :D

Comment: @nigel222 that was useful and helpful. I have created an additional timestamp field and ordered by that. Thanks for your comment!